# How to Enable scroll for specific div and disable scroll for page

Tags: css, scroll

Is it possible to disable scroll for the page, and only enable for a specific `div` inside the page?

Answer (score 25):

to disable it use:

**css**

```
.disableScroll{
      overflow-y:hidden;
      overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

just add `<body class="disableScroll">` to the disable

**inline style** `<body style="overflow:hidden">`

for div use, leave scrolling enabled `<div style="overflow:auto;">`

Keep in mind that you can use overflow-y for vertical scroll and overflow-x for horizontal scroll properties

Comment: why not just `overflow:hidden` instead of overflow-x and y ?

Comment: @Harsh to give more flexibility, in case he wants to disable vertical vs horizontal

Answer (score 16):

It's ok a css only solution?

If so, just add overflow: hidden to body and overflow: auto to the scrollable div.

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#scroller {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100px;
}
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/AYiJ/1/edit)

Comment: Absolute, css would be great. I have tried your code, it's working, but the scrollbar is hidden after the content. Also some items are not completely visible in the div #scroller.

Comment: what do you mean with the scrollbar is hidden after the content?

Comment: The browser scrollbar is after the content, so I can't use it anymore.. @patrick

Comment: can you pleas give me a screenshot?

Comment: 'overflow: auto;' did the secret.

Answer (score 2):

for whole page:

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

for div for example:

```
div.scroll {
    width:180px;
    height:170px;
    overflow:auto;

}
```

in html:

```
<div class='scroll'></div>
```

Comment: Make sure the BODY and HTML tags have no padding and margin, otherwise `width: 100%;` and `height: 100%` would push the edges out of bounds and create scroll bars anyway.

Comment: Hi @ArtsiomMitrokhin I have tried your codes. It's working, but when I reach the top or bottom you will see that you are able to scrolling. Only at bottom and top when reach the bottom of the content area with the class of scroll.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="scrollDisable"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.scrollDisable{
  overflow-y:hidden;
  overflow-x:hidden;
```

}

For whole page :

```
 body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Enable for specific div, disable for page.